# Is it bad practice to store data in a library?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm in the middle of creating a new library, and as I was building it something seemed a little odd.
Here's the code:

```
namespace traditional_poker
{
    public class poker
    {
       public class hand
        {
           public String Name
            {
                get; set;
            }
           public String[] cards
            {
                get; set;
            }

        }

        List<hand> players;

        public void AddPlayer(String name)
        {
            hand newHand = new hand();
            newHand.Name = name;
            players.Add(newHand);
        }
    }
}
```

I have `List<hand> players` inside the Library itself, which means the library is storing data (albeit temporarily).

Is this bad practice?

Is there a better way to do this?

Or is the way I'm doing it completely legitimate?

Comment: If it is temporary data no, if it should be saved for later usage yes.

Comment: Completely legitimate.  You are not storing data in a library; a class in your library has a member reference to a data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the way you want to tackle the problem.
If you want to have the data temporarily then it is Ok, If you want to save your data between different application instances or across different sessions then you should use a data persistent tool (filing, databases, ...)

```
namespace traditional_poker
{
    public class poker
    {
       public class hand // use PascalCaseNamingConvention
        {
           public String Name
            {
                get; set;
            }
           public String[] cards // use PascalCaseNamingConvention
            {
                get; set;
            }

        }

        List<hand> players;

        public void AddPlayer(String name)
        {
            hand newHand = new hand();
            newHand.Name = name;
            players.Add(newHand); //null reference exception here! you should initialize players
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and the code review).  It's been a couple years since I wrote a proper library, and wanted to make sure I wasn't making trouble for myself down the road.

Answer (score 2):

The library is not storing data.

It *offers functionality*, using classes, which have fields. These classes are  instantiated by an application using them, in the application memory space.

If it were bad practice to have data 'stored' in libraries, then libraries would not have classes or variables, and be severely limited.

Comment: Good point.  It looks like I've spent a little too much time in SQL Land, and have to remember the processing side of things again.